# How to decode BERT when BERT is binary string

Tags: erlang

I have [BERT](http://bert-rpc.org/) passed in to Erlang via a query string. I'm reading it via gen_tcp with the http_bin option so it arrives like this <<"131,104,1,100,0,2,104,105">>. Which is only almost right because I want to decode it with binary_to_term/2. But binary_to_term/2 wants a binary binary, not a string binary (it wants <<131,104,1,100,0,2,104,105>> not <<"131,104,1,100,0,2,104,105">>).

I can parse it to the right form like this.

```
parse(Source) ->
    Bins = binary:split(Source, <<",">>, [global]),
    parse(Bins, []).
parse([H | T], Acc) ->
    parse(T, [list_to_integer(binary_to_list(H)) | Acc]);
parse([], Acc) ->
    list_to_binary(lists:reverse(Acc)).
```

But this seems convoluted and is slower than I hoped (~5k/sec with each being 200 bytes). Also came up with something based on io_lib:fread/2 but it wasn't much better and still looks awkward.

1. Is there a BIF or NIF somewhere that might do this?
2. If not, is there a better way to do the above to speed it up?

Comment: This just makes me think that the thing building this query string is broken. I would recommend using something like base64 to encode the BERT for query string use.

Comment: Yeah, sending a binary as a string with comma separated integers is not very efficient or parsable. (As YOUR ARGUMENT IS VALID mentions, use the [Erlang `base64` library](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/base64.html) if you can)

Comment: I second that. It seems your client send an invalid BERT request.

Comment: Thanks! I think the query sting is ok. I'm pulling it by matching on {abs_path, HttpString} in gen_tcp:receive. HttpString is either type string() or binary(). But I think HttpString should be an untyped binary since gen_tcp is expecting the query string to be text not an ETF binary. Not sure how base64 would help since 131,104,1,100,0,2,104,105 is a valid ETF sequence. But I might be missing something....

Comment: And I was missing something. Thanks everyone who responded. Encoding BERT as text is a poor choice. Encoding BERT as base64 before inclusion in the query string allows you to use base64:decode/1 which returns a binary that can be passed to binary_to_term/2. Base64 is more compact. I'm able to parse the base64 binary string in about half the time as my parse function above. I get ~10k /sec for the same data mentioned above.

Comment: You might consider answering your own question now so it will be more useful when found in the future.

Comment: Sorry, but i can 't be encoded ;)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, an alternative solution - presumable slower, but possibly less ad-hoc, depending on taste - is to look at it as a problem of parsing a subset of Erlang, for which tools exist:

```
parse(Source) ->
  case erl_scan:string(Source++" .") of
    {ok, Tokens, _} ->
      case erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens) of
        {ok, Bin} when is_binary(Bin) -> % Only accept binary literals.
          Bin;
        _ -> error(badarg)
      end;
    _ -> error(badarg)
  end.
```

Possibly overkill in this context, but no more code than the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can parse up to 75MB/s in native (HiPE) and up to 17MB/s in byte code:

```
-module(str_to_bin).

-export([str_to_bin/1]).

str_to_bin(Bin) when is_binary(Bin) ->
  str_to_bin(Bin, <<>>).

-define(D(X), X >= $0, X =< $9 ).

-define(C(X), (X band 2#1111)).

str_to_bin(<<X,Y,Z,Rest/binary>>, Acc)
    when ?D(X), ?D(Y), ?D(Z) ->
  str_to_bin_(Rest, <<Acc/binary, (?C(X)*100 + ?C(Y)*10 + ?C(Z))>>);
str_to_bin(<<Y,Z,Rest/binary>>, Acc)
    when ?D(Y), ?D(Z) ->
  str_to_bin_(Rest, <<Acc/binary, (?C(Y)*10 + ?C(Z))>>);
str_to_bin(<<Z,Rest/binary>>, Acc)
    when ?D(Z) ->
  str_to_bin_(Rest, <<Acc/binary, ?C(Z)>>).

-compile({inline, [str_to_bin_/2]}).

str_to_bin_(<<>>, Acc) -> Acc;
str_to_bin_(<<$,, Rest/binary>>, Acc) -> str_to_bin(Rest, Acc).
```